# Failed to load network image in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to retrieve a network image from firebase and I found the below error:

```
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-portfolio-e615c.appspot.com/o/user%2FIMG_7344.jpg?alt=media&token=e7681a94-89f3-4a85-b8f8-83f346e91bd8
Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images
```

So I searched about the solution I found I can use one of the below commands and it works fine:

```
flutter run --web-renderer html

flutter build web --release --web-renderer html
```

So is there's another solution to run on debug mode without showing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is related to Cross Origin Resource Sharing, and in Flutter there is a good explanation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web-images#cross-origin-images). It gives specific examples for how to configure Firebase cross origin requests by modifying your firebase.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your **index.html** and the images will start appearing!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
</script>
```